# angular - paste in search ng select not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I try to apply search callback ng select in project angular5 but, search is working but when I apply copy-paste string in select doesn't work in the first time
code HTML

```
     <ng-select [items]="listRequesters" class="w-100" [loading]="loadingRequester" bindLabel="name"
                             [virtualScroll]="true" bindValue="id" (scrollToEnd)="getListRequesters()" 
                             [ngModel]="selectedRequester" name="coreUser" [searchFn]="searchRequesters" [clearable]="false"  
                             #coreUser="ngModel" (click)="setMarginRequester(coreUser.value)" typeToSearchText="{{'typeSearchText'|translate}}" 
                             (close)="setMarginRequester(coreUser.value)" dropdownPosition="bottom" [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
                             ngModel placeholder="{{'select'|translate}}.." (selectionChanges)="validateFirstStep('and')" required>
                             <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-requester="item" let-search="searchTerm">
                                <div [ngOptionHighlight]="search" class="text-uppercase">
                                   {{ requester.name }}
                                </div>
                             </ng-template>
```

code ts:

```
     setMarginRequester(value) {
        const requesters = Object.assign([], this.requestersInit);
        requesters.forEach(element => {
            if (this.listRequesters.filter(x => x.id == element.id).length == 0) {
                this.listRequesters.push(element);
            }
        });        
        this.listRequesters = [...this.listRequesters];
        this.listRequesters.sort(this.compare);
    }

    searchRequesters(term: string, item) {
        term = term.toLowerCase();
        return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1 || item.name.toLowerCase() === term;       
    }
    getListRequesters() {
       // this.listRequesters = [];
        this.indexRequester = this.indexRequester + this.limit;
        if (this.poPurchaseOrder.coreAgency && this.poPurchaseOrder.coreAgency.coreUserAdditionals) {
            Object.values(this.poPurchaseOrder.coreAgency.coreUserAdditionals).forEach((element, key) => {
                this.loadingRequester = true;
                if (this.listRequesters.length <= (this.listRequesters.length + this.limit)) {
                    this.listRequesters.push(element);
                }

            });
        }
        this.listRequesters = this.commonService.removeDuplicateObjectFromArray(this.listRequesters);
        this.listRequesters.forEach(element => {
            element['name'] = element.firstName + ' ' + element.lastName;
        });
        this.listRequesters.sort(this.compare);
        this.listRequesters = [...this.listRequesters];
        this.loadingRequester = false;
    }
```

error is when I paste string in first time search dosen't working but when i delete search string and paste otherwise search is working ...

Comment: Your problem is not clear

Comment: @canbax when I copy paste a string for the first time the search does not work, but after that if we modify the search string or make another copy paste another time must work

Comment: Any help please

Comment: try using `(change)='searchRequesters()'" `, just add it to ng-select